# Diff module not working. Compare shows 'no visible changes'

Tags: 7

I have installed the [diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/diff) module on my D7 site. I can see the different revisions on the revisions tab, but clicking 'compare' always shows 'no visible changes'. I think I must have missed something obvious, but am struggling to work out what.

On the admin/structure/types/manage/ page for my content type I have gone to the 'Publishing options and enabled the 'Create new revision' option. On the 'Compare revisions' tab  'Show View changes button on node edit form' and 'Enable the Revisions page for this content type' are checked. 'Standard comparison preview' is set to 'Full content'. I have left the options at 'admin/config/content/diff' and 'admin/config/content/diff/fields' to their defaults. I am logged in as user 1.

My nodes don't have any main body content, only individual fields. Could you please suggest what I need to do to show the diffs.

UPDATE:
I have tested in a sandbox server and the diff module works as expected. Therefore it must be a conflict or a bug that is being triggered by my install.

UPDATE:
After more investigation I have discovered that the issue exists only with pre-existing fields. So am starting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had disabled hidden all my fields in the default view which was why the diff wasn't showing.

I fixed this by:
On the page admin/structure/types/manage/mynodetype I changed the 'standard comparison preview' from 'Full content' to 'Revision comparison'.

I then went to admin/structure/types/manage/mynodetype/display, opened the collapsed field 'custom display settings' and checked 'Revision comparison'. Then in the revision comparison view that was created I made sure the format for each field was no longer set to 'hidden'. Now the diff module is working as expected.

This issue is also discussed in this [drupal answers question](https://www.drupal.org/node/2577511)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be this:

> On the admin/structure/types/manage/ page for my content type I have
>   gone to the 'Publishing options and enabled the 'Create new revision'
>   option.

Because of the above setting even if you edit a node and save without any change, a new revision is created. The new revision has no possible changes that are visible except for `update date`. I think you should uncheck this setting `Create new revision` and let content writers to create revision if they edited the node.

I tested it locally and was able to reproduce it. Revision was created if you edit and save the node without any changes.
[image]
[image]

After manually create a revision after change:
[image]

Comment: Hi Vishal. Its great that you have managed to replicate the problem. But have you also been able to show the solution? I have tried going to admin/structure/types/manage/ page for my content type and disabling the 'Create new revision' option. I have then edited a node of that type and manually created the revision. I still get 'No visible changes'.

Comment: sorry. But if i change and create a new revision. i can see the difference.

Comment: using the latest diff version. 7.x-3.2.